# Problemas con un UPDATE de php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fileupload, upload

Chic@s, quiero subir una imagen a mi servidor y luego pasarle el nombre al usuario en la base de datos para que se visualice como foto de perfil, "el problema".. no me añade el nombre del archivo, aun que ya posee los valores, creo que algo estoy haciendo mal con el UPDATE...

aqui el PHP

```
<?php
include("../getR.php");
session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id_usuarios'])) {
        header("Location: ../index.php");
    }
#Rescato nombre de variable e ID de usuario
$nombre_img=$_FILES['imagen']['name'];
$iduser = $_SESSION['id_usuarios'];

if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"]))

{
# Defino las variables
$host="servidor";
$port=puerto;
$user="usuario";
$password="contraseña";
$ruta="";

# Realizo la conexion con el servidor
$conn_id=@ftp_connect($host,$port);
if($conn_id) {
    # Realizo el login con mi usuario y contraseña
    if(@ftp_login($conn_id,$user,$password)){
        # Cambio al directorio especificado
        if(@ftp_chdir($conn_id,$ruta)){
            # Subo el fichero
            if(@ftp_put($conn_id,$_FILES["imagen"]["name"],$_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"],FTP_BINARY))
                echo ("Imagen subida con exito" . $iduser);
            else
                echo "Error al subir imagen";
        }else   
            echo "No existe carpeta de destino";
    }else
        echo "El usuario o la contraseña son incorrectos";
    # Cierro la conexion ftp
    ftp_close($conn_id);
}else
    echo "No ha sido posible conectar con el servidor";
}else{
    echo "Selecciona un archivo...";
}
```

para finalizar el archivo PHP le paso un mysqli

```
#Envio a la BD los valores
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
$sql="UPDATE UsrCtrl01 SET pic='$nombre_img' WHERE idusuarios='$iduser'";
$resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Has depurado algo? Por ejemplo, ¿este mensaje lo ves en pantalla: `echo ("Imagen subida con exito" . $iduser);`? ¿verificaste que la conexión está activa? ¿verificaste si no hay errores de clave duplicada? ¿depuraste la variable `$nombre_img` al momento de hacer el `UPDATE`. Son pasos mínimos de depuración que deberías realizar y decirnos la situación.

Comment: si claro, conecta con el servidor, las variables llevan el valor, veo el ```echo``` y el update parece estar correcto pues cuando lo ejecuto en linea en mysql modifica el usuario... no se que estoy haciendo mal...

Answer (score 1):

En algunas respuestas yo he hablado de *programación pesimista*, es decir, muchos programadores son víctima de un cierto optimismo al escribir código pensando que siempre todo irá bien. Ojalá fuera así, pero no siempre todo va bien y cuando hay algún fallo ese estilo *optimista* de programar no es capaz de responder a ese fallo.

En un escenario tan simple como el tuyo lo *pésimo* puede ocurrir al menos por **tres motivos** y debes controlarlo:

1. La conexión puede ser nula o inválida, lo mismo que las dos variables que participan en el `UPDATE`
2. Puede ocurrir un error ejecutando la consulta (de sintaxis, porque hay una columna mal escrita, porque esa tabla ya no existe, porque pusiste algo mal escribiendo la consulta, porque un hacker novato **¡preparó mal su inyección de código resultando en una consulta errónea!** (en ese punto me alegro por ti, pero te pongo eso en negrita para decirte que tu consulta es muy vulnerable), y así hay mil motivos por los que una consulta puede fallar.
3. Puede que la consulta sea correcta, pero que no se actualice ninguna fila. Eso ocurre por ejemplo cuando mandas a actualizar seteando datos idénticos a los que ya existen.

Como podrás comprender, ninguno de esos tres posibles escenarios ha sido previsto en tu código. Te propongo este estilo de programación *pesimista*  en el cual controlas cualquier eventualidad, recogiéndola en una variable `$msg`. Se trata de un código robusto, que no se quedará mudo ante situaciones de fallo, mientras el usuario, del otro lado, después de esperar y esperar, se da cuenta de que algo anda mal o peor aún cree que todo ocurrió como se esperaba, que la actualización se hizo sin haberlo comprobado realmente... y se da cuenta, a las varias horas, días, meses o años, que ciertas actualizaciones no se llegaron a hacer nunca y quizá eso hizo que durante horas, días, semanas, meses o años se haya estado trabajando con información errónea.

```
#Envio a la BD los valores
mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
#1. Verificamos que todos los datos son correctos
if ($conexion && $nombre_img && $iduser) {
    $sql="UPDATE UsrCtrl01 SET pic='$nombre_img' WHERE idusuarios='$iduser'";
    #2. Verificamos que no hay error ejecutando query
    if ( $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql) ) {
        #3. Verificamos si hubo filas afectadas
        $rows=mysqli_affected_rows($conexion);
        $msg= ($rows > 0) ? "Se actualizaron $rows filas" : "Error: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
    } else {
        #Obtenemos un eventual mensaje de error
        #En producción evitar el uso de mysqli_error ▲  y ▼
        #cambiarlo por mensajes personalizados
        $msg="Error ejecutando la consulta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
    }
} else {
    $msg="La conexión es nula o alguna de las variables está vacía";
}
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Agradezco y anticipo toda la ayuda que me brindan, especialmente usted que veo que domina muchisimo el tema (aprecio su tiempo tambien), intente con la modificacion del codigo, y se ejecuta el ```echo $msg; (vacio)``` pero no hace cambios en la BD....

Comment: @DevR41 Prueba a poner un `var_dump($msg);` para ver lo que hay en la variable realmente.